# Android: keyboard layout files

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Is there a repository of international keyboard layout files (in the XML format that Android supports), either the ones that come with stock Android or any third party repository? (Background is that I'd like to use them as source for a custom softkeyboard for a non-Android system.)

(for clarification: I'm not interested in creating a custom keyboard, I'm interested in the XML files for existing international keyboards.)

Comment: Your question is unclear? Add some relevant code & explain wat you have tried & wat you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, [here](https://github.com/marcosdiez/aosp-morelang-ime/tree/master/java/res/xml) is a mirror of the default AOSP keyboard definition files.